# Replace filename using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Can someone show me how to do the following in JavaScript? I know how to grab the src of the image, I just want to be able to replace the filename with something new.

> /image/any/path/ANY-TEXT_HERE.png
>
> /image/any/path/NEWTEXT.png

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Case-insensitive version:

```
path = path.replace(/(.*)\/.*(\.png$)/i, '$1/NEWTEXT$2')
```

Remove the i after / to make it case-sensitive.

Comment: @ridge, my understanding is that the path is fixed.  I think the only part of the source string that varies is 'ANY-TEXT_HERE'.

Comment: That is correct. There will always be an image. The trick is to just be able to define a new file name.

Comment: +1 .. can you edit Regex so that it can work with INSENSITIVE case ('png', 'Png', 'PNG') ?

Answer (score 2):

```
var url = "/image/any/path/ANY-TEXT_HERE.png";
var mystring = "NEWTEXT";
var ind1 = url .lastIndexOf('/');
var ind2 = url .lastIndexOf('.');

var new_url = url.substring(0,ind1+1 )+ mystring + url.substring(ind2 );
alert(new_url );
```

Comment: Fastest one yet, but fails when the filename has more than one dot in it.

Comment: without specifying the possible input string domain, nothing concrete could be drawn.

Comment: changing: `ind2 = url .indexOf('.');` to: `ind2 = url .lastIndexOf('.');` fixes the dot problem.

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
var filename = "/image/any/path/NEWTEXT.png";
var splitFilename = filename.split("/");
var newPath = splitFilename.slice(0, splitFilename.length - 1).join("/")
if (newPath.length !== 0) {
    newPath += "/"
}
newPath += newFilename;
```

Answer (score 1):

All the other solutions so far assume there actually *IS* a path. They work only if there is at least one forward slash. This tested functions works in all cases including an empty path:

```js
function rename_img_file(text, newname)
{ // Rename file in a IMG src (no query or fragment)
    var re = /^(.*\/)?[^\/]+\.(png|gif|jpe?g)$/i;
    var rep_str = '$1' + newname + '.$2';
    text = text.replace(re, rep_str);
    return text;
}
```

Comment: doesnt work at all.  edit it to var rep_str = '$1NEWTEXT.$2';

Answer (score 0):

javascript its really restrictive to files.
I assume that you want to do that on a server. if that so, you should use a serverside script, not a client side.
Maybe you ar talking about an ajax script
if you can explain a ltl further maybe i can lendyou a hand